# JavaFX TabPane: separate tabs from their content

Tags: tabs, javafx

I would like to create a tabbed JavaFX layout like on the picture below (this is a recent Firefox version window):

[image: Tabs then some fields, then tab contents]

Is it possible to somehow insert fixed content between tabs and tab contents when using **javafx.scene.control.TabPane**? The same fixed content (e.g. address bar and favorites panel on the screenshot) should be shown for each selected tab.

Comment: That's not really "fixed" content; they are different instances of the location bar, etc. (or at least, that's the obvious way to implement it). If you think about the location field, each one has a different text value in it; for the search field, each one handles the action differently (it loads the search results into different tabs).

Comment: Btw, my initial statement was incorrect - in Firefox address bar contains different address for each tab. However I would like to have only one instance of address bar and not a separate bar for each tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can share the node with the "fixed" content between tabs, and reparent it to the selected tab's [content](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Tab.html#contentProperty--) each time a tab is selected.

Please note that TabPane doesn't seem to be designed with browser-kind usecase in mind. For example, its tabs are not draggable.